# Why do i need to press '\n' three times for this to run?

Tags: c, loops

hi does anyone know why this code makes me press enter three times before it runs? I need it for a school assignment to run at the first '\n'
here is the code: thank you very much!!

```
int main()
{
    char  L1=0, L2=0, L3=0 ;
    int count_hya=0, countLA=0, countLC=0, countLH=0, countLL=0 ;
    printf("give me some letters\n");

    while ((L1!='\n')&&(L2!='\n')&&(L3!='\n'))
    {
        L1=getchar();
        if (L1=='A')
            countLA++;
        if (L1=='C')
            countLC++;
        if (L1=='L')
            countLL++;
        if (L1=='H')
            countLH++;
        if (L1=='H'&&L2=='Y'&&L3=='A')
            count_hya++;
    }
    printf("number of words begning with: A=%d  C=%d  L=%d  H=%d Hydra=%d", 
           countLA, countLC, countLL, countLH, count_hya);
    return 0;
}
```

edit changed the last few lines to:

```
 if (L1=='H')
  {   
  countLH++;
  L2=getchar();
  L3=getchar();
  if (L1=='H'&&L2=='Y'&&L3=='A')
   count_hya++;
  }
```

and works like a charm thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: how your input looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
scanf("%c%c%c", &L1, &L2, &L3);
```

Will read 3 characters. If you press enter once, it will read one character, and waits for more.

You may need to press enter up to 5 times, actually, if you input

```
1<enter>
<enter>
<enter>
<enter>
<enter>
```

---

One solution is to read char by char (then you may use `getchar()` instead of `scanf("%c");`). Other solution would be to read entire line at once (with `fgets()` probably).

Since this is schoolwork, I'm not going to write a solution for you though :)

Comment: oh! i see so how should i fix this? because i still need to somehow keep count of the number of words that start with the important letters and figure out if the word HYA is in the input

Comment: @user3052371 Well, ugly solution is to read 1 character 3 times, to different variable each time, and after each one test if it was `'\n'`, with copy-paste code.

Answer (score 2):

the while you use:

```
while ((L1!='\n')||(L2!='\n')||(L3!='\n'))
```

should be

```
while ((L1!='\n')&&(L2!='\n')&&(L3!='\n'))
```

Use the following code

```
#define SCANF_CHK(L) \
     scanf("%c", &L); \
     if(L=='\n') continue;

int main()
{
    char  L1=0, L2=0, L3=0 ;
    int count_hya=0, countLA=0, countLC=0, countLH=0, countLL=0 ;
    printf("give me some letters\n");
    while ((L1!='\n')&&(L2!='\n')&&(L3!='\n'))
    {
        SCANF_CHK(L1);
        SCANF_CHK(L2);
        SCANF_CHK(L3);
        if (L1=='A')
            countLA++;
        if (L1=='C')
            countLC++;
        if (L1=='L')
            countLL++;
        if (L1=='H')
            countLH++;
        if (L1=='H'&&L2=='Y'&&L3=='A')
            count_hya++;
    }
    printf("number of words begning with: A=%d  C=%d  L=%d  H=%d Hydra=%d\n", 
           countLA, countLC, countLL, countLH, count_hya);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3052371 if your input is `ANDCAMCOMCNCCASHERLEOLYRHY\n` then it will works

Answer (score 0):

You have to press three times /n not to start a program but to stop it . This is a condition in while. Three inputs ( l1 , l2, l3 ) must be /n to leave a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
char  L1=0, L2=0, L3=0 ;
int count_hya=0, countLA=0, countLC=0, countLH=0, countLL=0 ;
int flag=1;
printf("give me some letters\n");

while (flag==1)
{
    if(flag==1)
     {scanf("%c",&L1);
      if( L1=='\n')
         flag=0;
     }

    if(flag==1) 
      {scanf("%c",&L2);
       if( L2=='\n')
         flag=0;
      }
    if(flag==1) 
     {scanf("%c",&L3);
       if( L3=='\n')
         flag=0;
      }
    if (L1=='A')
        countLA++;
    if (L1=='C')
        countLC++;
    if (L1=='L')
        countLL++;
    if (L1=='H')
        countLH++;
    if (L1=='H'&&L2=='Y'&&L3=='A')
        count_hya++;
}
printf("number of words begning with: A=%d  C=%d  L=%d  H=%d Hydra=%d", 
       countLA, countLC, countLL, countLH, count_hya);
return 0;
```

}

In the above code, you will read the following char ONLY if the previous one was different from '\n'. This way, you will never need to press '\n' three times.

Comment: Why does the app require enter three times?  Your post doesn't answer the question.

Comment: He said he needs it for an assignment, so probably he also needs a valid solution.

Comment: A working solution to demonstrate the answer is great, but answering the question itself is even better.  Look at the accepted answer for a good example.